# Проверка онлайна человека на сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возьмем абстрактный сервер, который работает с клиентами(допустим, мессенджер VK или что-то похожее). При заходе в ветку сообщений мы можем увидеть, в сети человек или нет.

Может ли кто подсказать, как это работает? Какие механизмы используются и на что смотреть в процессе создания такого же функционала в формате собственного обучения?

И еще такой вопрос, все тот же самый сервер для мессенджера, после разрыва соединения, как он понимает, что я хочу отправить сообщение конкретно этому человеку, а не кому-то другому? Ведь соединение уже разорвано. Что на эту тему почитать?

Comment: Соединение с ним кого? О каком онлайне вообще речь?

Comment: @andreymal, допустим, как в вк. Я же могу видеть, онлайн человек сейчас или нет, вот как этот процесс работает в целом?

Comment: Приложение иногда вызывает API-метод [account.setOnline](https://dev.vk.com/method/account.setOnline) и таким образом обновляет запись о дате последнего посещения. А если вызывать не будет — человек будет отображаться оффлайн, даже если он сидит в ВК прямо сейчас

Comment: Как вариант через сокеты ещё. Если по сокету есть ответ, значит онлайн, если нет, то убивается по timeout.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос. Сейчас непонятно про какой именно сервер и онлайн речь. Если вы хотите про то, как в принципе такие вещи работают, а не про конкретный сервер, то это тоже нужно обозначить в вопросе. И лучше приводить какие-то примеры в вопросе. Вот как вы привели пример с ВК в комментарии. Всё это должно быть прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Последний абзац непонятен от слова совсем. Какое отношение имеет соединение к отправке сообщения? Отправитель просто указывает идентификатор получателя при отправке сообщения (в том же ВК смотрите API-метод [messages.send](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.send), параметр user_id), а есть ли соединение или нет — не имеет вообще никакого значения

Comment: @andreymal а потом методу разве не нужно знать айпишник, на который высылать?

Comment: @ЛевПряхин никто никому ничего не высылает, получатель сам отправляет серверу запрос [messages.getConversations](https://dev.vk.com/method/messages.getConversations), чтобы узнать, есть ли какие-то непрочитанные сообщения

Comment: (в принципе конечно можно и по айпишнику высылать, но это уже совершенно другой класс мессенджеров и популярные сервисы вроде ВК так не делают)

Comment: @andreymal, тогда последний уточняющий вопрос, сообщение записывается же в базу данных, откуда уже по запросу отправляется к клиенту?

Comment: @ЛевПряхин да .

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно почитать о websocket. У каждого пользователя есть id и сообщение сохраняется в базе данных по user id. И нет разницы пользователь online или offline. Главное что-бы база данных в онлайне была.