# Как отследить активность пользователя телеграм бота?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, бот

Подскажите, как проверить чат на активность? Допустим пользователь вводит команду(/open) для начала запись чего либо (например оценок, и отправляет он их НЕ одним сообщением а несколькими), и при завершении так же отправляет команду(/close). Но вот как отследить если на протяжении допустим 5-ти минут от пользователя не приходит сообщений, чтобы автоматически закрыть сессию

p.s: все данные о пользователе имеются и хранятся в SQLite

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проверка онлайна человека на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1481884/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Через модуль sleep, поставить таймер на 5 минут, после истечении времени, проверить, отправлял ли юрез сообщения

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]